# SharePoint Team Site - Navigation menu displayed differently

Tags: sharepoint-2013, navigationbar, teamsite

I was wondering why the navigation menu in team sites looks different on different pages/sub-sites.

To give you an example:

How it should look site-wide:
It seems that this menu is only appearing on https://***.*******.***/_layouts/15/settings.aspx

[image]

How the main page appears:

[image]

Is there any way I could fix this so that the menu in the first image is displayed site-wide? The menu in the first image is only view-able in some sub-sites but not the main page for example.

Also is it possible to remove the 'National Statistics Office' (site name) from the navigation bar?

Code in seattle masterpage (html)

`<style type="text/css">
    .ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > a{
    display: none !important;
    }
    .ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > ul a{
    display: block !important;
    }
    .menu-item-text
    {
    display: none;
    }
    .additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow
    {
    display: none;
    }
</style>`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit the top level navigation from the parent site if you go to site settings > Navigation > Global Navigation: use navigation items from parent site (first option, badly translated from my mother language) :)

To hide the site title, yes this is possible but through using css. Use your browser developer tools (F12), try to find a class or an identifier and hide it through css in your master page. It should look something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > a{
display: none !important;
}
.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > ul a{
display: block !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately 'Use Navigation Items from parent site' is not clickable and whenever I try to modify the master page it prompts me to save it under another name.

Comment: You are logged in as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I am a site owner and have full rights on the portal.

Comment: I have modified the master page (html) and included the following `<style type="text/css">
 .ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > a{
 display: none !important;
 }
 .ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > ul a{
 display: block !important;
 }
 .menu-item-text
 {
 display: none;
 }
 .additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow
 {
 display: none;
 }
</style>`  but the National Statistics Office is still appearing.

Comment: Just have a look with the developer tools of your browser (f12) and click the link you want to hide. Use that ID to hide it with css or jquery. The example i gave is possible to not be the same as your ids/classes